# Invalid Attribute name while getting collection : Magento

Tags: magento

I am getting the following error -

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Eav_Exception' with message 'Invalid attribute name: subcategory_id.' in /home/dev-cm/public_html/magento2/app/Mage.php:536 Stack trace: #0 /home/dev-cm/public_html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1155)
Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Invalid attribu...') #1 /home/dev-cm/public_html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1240)
```

I have actually added a custom field directly to the table in the database. It was already a custom table too. For making entries too setSubcategoryId() method didn't work. So I saved it through making db connection and saving it through query which is not good idea.

But getSubcategoryId() method worked for getting this field value from collection. Now I am trying to get records for filtering through this field but it's not working and showing the above error. Below is the code that's showing this error -

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/merchant')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('subcategory_id','123');
```

I searched about it a lot but didn't found any solution. I also flushed magenta cache and re-indexed data but it didn't work. I think I need changes in core files but I don't know what and how to do them.

So I need to get setSubcategoryId() method and the above error fixed for this custom field

Comment: try `addAttributeToFilter()`

Comment: Tried `addAttributeToFilter()` too. But same error.

Comment: You should provide your config.xml and model files for further assistance. You definitely made a mistake in `Model` of your module. And if you can provide intention of your module in your question, that will prodcuce a better understanding of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are extending the wrong collection... you are using (extending) an eav collection while you should extend a mysql4 collection.